# 'Select by attribute' using python in ArcMap 10

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, sql

I need to select a feature using SQL before zooming to it in python.  What I'm looking for are replacements for the commented lines in this code:

```
import arcpy
parcel_num = "123456"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
# df.selectFeatures("SELECT * FROM LandRecords.GISDBA.Parcels "
#                   "WHERE PARCEL_NUM='%s'" % parcel_num)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have "LandRecords.GISDBA.Parcels" as a layer in your map document and the layer name is set to "Parcels" you should be able to do this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
parcels = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapDoc, "Parcels", df)[0]

whereClause = "PARCEL_NUM ='%s'" % parcel_num
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(parcels, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
df.extent = parcels.getSelectedExtent(True)
df.scale *= 1.5
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Note: my experience so far is changing the map extents automatically refreshes the map. I only call `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` when I manually manipulate the `df.scale`.

Comment: You could skip the ListLayers and just issue `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Parcels", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not up to scratch with the ArcPy module (not using version 10 yet) but previous python code would require you to get a handle on a layer then do a select on it. I grabbed this from the online help:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ("C:/data/data.mdb/states", "stateslyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("stateslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", " [NAME] = 'California' ")
```

[Click here to go to online Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Attribute/001700000071000000/)